# Why does codeblocks ide raise: fatal error: iostream: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

when I run this test code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << end1;
    return 0;
}
```

with a more than less than around iostream just can't use it on stackover flow.
I got this code from an old book (2014) it might be outdated. I've never used C++ before how do I fix this.

Comment: The shown code is fine. Your C++ compiler installation is either corrupted or misconfigured, in some unknown way.

Comment: Does your IDE (Code::Blocks) believe that your code is C++? Maybe your code is being compiled as C instead? Comment out (or remove) the `#include` line -- does your compiler complain about `using namespace std;` (which is valid C++, but not valid C)?

Comment: @jaMiT Thanks that's it. You're very helpful. It was thinking it was just c